# Create a notebook application in java?

Tags: java, graphics, javafx

First of all this is just a fun project. I have a idea to make a notebook software using java.
i know there are many softwares,but this is for my knowledge. I need do following tasks in my application,

1. Expand typing area when neccessary (like in Onenote)
2. Draw shapes and edit shapes
3. Add code,syntax inside a note and it can be move (can i add this part to a jPanel?)
4. Add comments to a line in a bubble
5. Add some simple notes like sticky notes in a note
6. Also i need to add a mini map of a note (How to get the copy of the working note?)

(Solved)  07. Also I decided to use javaFX to create the interface, Is JavaFX good for my project?

Can i do all of these in java?
If can please give me some guide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look at [Getting Started with JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah.. It is definitely possible to write a code for your requirement in javafx. Since you are a beginner start with this documentations.

You can download Javafx documentation in the following link. 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/java-se-7-doc-download-435117.html

Also I would recommend you to download this JavaFX SDK, which includes all the documentations. 
http://javafx.com/downloads/